# Stub or Mock IMapper Returning Derived Classes where Base Expected

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, automapper, moq, stub

I have a class that takes in an `IMapper` in the constructor like this

```
public Foo(IMapper mapper)
```

In the code for Foo I have this line

```
var dao = _mapper.Map<BaseDAO>(obj);
```

`BaseDAO` has 3 subtypes that in the real code I have set up like this

```
CreateMap<Base, BaseDAO>()
     .Include<Child1, Child1DAO>()
     .Include<Child2, Child2DAO>()
     .Include<Child3, Child3DAO>();
```

I would like to mock out the above line

```
var dao = _mapper.Map<BaseDAO>(obj);
```

so that if a `Child1` is passed in then a `Child1DAO` will be returned and the same for the other subtypes.  I tried to stub out `IMapper` but the following method returns an error saying that

> Child1DAO cannot be implicitly converted to a TDestination

and I tried to mock out `IMapper` but could not get that to work either.

```
public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
{
    return new Child1DAO();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this example, assume the following class is the subject under test

```
public class Foo {
    private IMapper mapper;
    public Foo(IMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public BaseDAO Bar(object obj) {
        var dao = mapper.Map<BaseDAO>(obj);
        return dao;
    }
}
```

Where the [`IMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IMapper.cs) dependency has the following contract defined

```
public interface IMapper {
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a mapping from the source object to a new destination object.
    /// The source type is inferred from the source object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination">Destination type to create</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Source object to map from</param>
    /// <returns>Mapped destination object</returns>
    TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source);

    //...
}
```

The following test demonstrates, using moq,

> Mock IMapper Returning Derived Classes where Base Expected

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void _TestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<IMapper>();
        var foo = new Foo(mock.Object);

        mock
            //setup the mocked function
            .Setup(_ => _.Map<BaseDAO>(It.IsAny<object>()))
            //fake/stub what mocked function should return given provided arg
            .Returns((object arg) => {
                if (arg != null && arg is Child1)
                    return new Child1DAO();
                if (arg != null && arg is Child2)
                    return new Child2DAO();
                if (arg != null && arg is Child3)
                    return new Child3DAO();

                return null;
            });

        var child1 = new Child1();

        //Act
        var actual = foo.Bar(child1);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(BaseDAO));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(Child1DAO));
    }
}
```